# linux. filter all the lines of folder files and add them up in a single file

Tags: linux, parsing, awk

I have a folder with files like:

```
pe1_file1.txt
pe1_file2.txt
px1_file3.txt
px1_file4.txt  etc

every file has lines such:
1123343 34 SDSD XV34 nameofdatabase 34 45455 4545 
1145343 33 SD34 XT45 nameofdatabase 34 45455 4545
```

I would like to parse all the files of that folder (actually there are a bunch of folders) and build up a single text file that includes all the lines of all those text files that comply with a particular condition. The resulting file should only contain the first 5 values (up to nameofdatabase) AND the 3 first letters of the name of the file.

I tend to use the following code modified:
The following passes all the filtered lines and with all the values. I want to omit the last three numbers and add "pe1" or "px2" as first value.

```
for FILE in files/*.txt;
do
  firstchar=${FILE:0:4}
  # how do I modify the nest line in order to add $firstchar ("pe1") and $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6 ???
  awk '$3=="SDSD"&&$4=="cardatabase"' $FILE.txt >> TOTAL.txt
done
```

Comment: The first 4 letters or the first 3?

Comment: Don't you want `$3=="SDSD"`?

Answer (score 3):

there is no loop required

```
$ awk '$3=="SDSD" && $4=="cardatabase" 
           {print substr(FILENAME, 1, 4), $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6}'  files/*.txt > total.txt
```

note that substr indexing starts with 1.  Most likely `$4` should be `$5` based on your sample input.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` conveniently defines the variable `FILENAME` holding the current file name and provides the function `substr` to extract a substring:

```
for FILE in files/*.txt;
do
  awk '$3=="SDSD"&&$4=="cardatabase"{print substr(FILENAME, 1, 4), $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' "$FILE"
done > TOTAL.txt
```

You can avoid opening the result file multiple times by only redirecting the complete output of the loop once.

---

Update after the comment by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton):

awk can totally open multiple files at once. So as long as you do not have any other actions to take with each file, run awk directly:

```
awk '$3=="SDSD"&&$4=="cardatabase"{print substr(FILENAME, 1, 4), $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' files/* > TOTAL.txt
```

Comment: @knittl what if I assume the whole text will not fit in the compuer memory, I can not do all the parsing and then pass it to the file TOTAL.txt. I modified your code making >> TOTAL.txt inside the loop (before done) but it does not work. COuld you please post both versions?

Comment: @JFerro there is nothing kept in memory other than the current record, it works line by line.

Comment: @Jferro doing `>> TOTAL.txt` inside the loop is just a less efficient way of doing `> TOTAL.txt` outside of the loop (plus you'd need to init the output file before the loop if you were appending to it inside).

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the clarificaying regarding 0 offset. I totally missed that the loop is redudnant here.

Comment: @JFerro Why does the whole text need to fit in memory? `awk` loads the text line by line (rather: record by record) and `>` writes to the file continuously as the output is generated